# Instantiated Prefab giving a NullReferenceException in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've looked at other Stack Overflow posts and Unity forum threads and still have not found an answer to why my code is failing. I've checked the prefabs' values multiple times, which are 100% not null (Both the `Debug.Log` lines aren't passing through, and getting some base data from them still works).
Neither `cardGameObject` nor `characterGameObject` can be null because they are initialized in the line that is throwing the `NullReferenceException`.

```
public void EnterCombat()
    {
        card  = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefabs/Card");
        characterModel = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefabs/Character");
        if(card == null)
            Debug.Log("Null Card");
        if(characterModel == null)
            Debug.Log("Null Character");
        GCC = encounter._GCC;
        // ***TEMP***
        DeckManager.SetActiveIndex(0);
        DeckManager.SetCrew(new DeckManager.Deck(new CharacterSO[] {Resources.Load<CharacterSO>("ScriptableObjects/Characters/Temp1"), Resources.Load<CharacterSO>("ScriptableObjects/Characters/Temp2"), Resources.Load<CharacterSO>("ScriptableObjects/Characters/Temp4"), null}), 0);
        // ***TEMP***
        buttons = new bool[]{false, false, false, false};
        for(int i = 3; i <= 10; i++)
                transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(false);
        foreach(CharacterSO character in DeckManager.GetActiveCrew().GetCrew())
            if(character != null)
                InstantiateMember(character, true, true, true);
        foreach(CharacterSO character in encounter.GetFirstWave())
            if(character != null)
                InstantiateMember(character, false, false, true);
        GCC.StartTurnSubscription(OnNewTurn);
        GCC.EndTurnSubscription(OnTurnEnd);
        GCC.EndCombatSubscription(OnCombatEnd);
        GCC.JoinCombatSubscription(OnJoiningCombat);
        GCC.StartCombat(this, encounter);
    }

private void InstantiateMember(CharacterSO character, bool allied, bool control, bool isCombatStart)
    {
        GameObject cardGameObject = Instantiate(card);
        cardGameObject.GetComponent<CardDataImplementor>().Character = character;
        cardGameObject.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
        cardGameObject.GetComponent<ObjectCombatManager>().IsAllied = allied;
        cardGameObject.GetComponent<ObjectCombatManager>().PlayerControl = control;
        cardGameObject.GetComponent<ObjectCombatManager>()._GCC = GCC;
        cardGameObject.GetComponent<CardDataImplementor>()._GCC = GCC;
        GameObject characterGameObject = Instantiate(characterModel);
        cardGameObject.GetComponent<ObjectCombatManager>().CharacterObject = characterGameObject;
        characterGameObject.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
        characterGameObject.GetComponent<CardToCharacter>().Card = cardGameObject;
        characterGameObject.GetComponent<CardToCharacter>()._GCC = GCC;
        characterGameObject.transform.localScale = new UnityEngine.Vector3(40f, 40f, 1f);
        UnityEngine.Vector3 vector = (allied ? alliedAmount : enemyAmount) switch
        {
            0 => new UnityEngine.Vector3(460f * (allied ? 1f : -1f), -15f, 0f),
            1 => new UnityEngine.Vector3(350f * (allied ? 1f : -1f), 125f, 0f),
            2 => new UnityEngine.Vector3(230f * (allied ? 1f : -1f), -15f, 0f),
            3 => new UnityEngine.Vector3(120f * (allied ? 1f : -1f), 125f, 0f),
            _ => UnityEngine.Vector3.zero
        };
        characterGameObject.transform.SetLocalPositionAndRotation(vector, UnityEngine.Quaternion.identity);
        characterGameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = cardGameObject.GetComponent<CardDataImplementor>().Character.CharacterArt;
        if(allied)
            alliedAmount++;
        else
            enemyAmount++;
        if(!isCombatStart)
        {
            characterGameObject.GetComponent<CardToCharacter>().EnterCombat();
            cardGameObject.GetComponent<ObjectCombatManager>().EnterCombat();
            cardGameObject.GetComponent<CardDataImplementor>().EnterEvents();
        }
    }
```

I get the error on the following lines:

`GameObject cardGameObject = Instantiate(card);`

`GameObject characterGameObject = Instantiate(characterModel);`

The prefabs exist inside the folder and making the prefabs a `[SerializeField]` and dragging in the prefab from the editor also doesn't work.

To top it all off, this exact code used to work but after changing a completely separate class it suddenly started crashing...

Edit 1: I have been sent the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), but it doesn't solve my problem. Neither the pointer nor the prefab are null. Also, I have attached an image showing that the Prefabs do in fact exist inside the Resources folder

[image: Folder]

Comment: are you sure your prefabs folder is where it needs to be? if its not in resources that wont work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please give us exact stack trace. If error happens on Instantiating prefab and the reference is not null I bet something wrong is happening in Awake/Start/OnEnable on one of the prefab scripts, also try not using .GetComponent repetitevly, instead use it once and store in local variable. That's like rule number 1 in optimization. Sorry for being snippy but when I see GetComponent called 12 times in one method it's a red flag for me and may be helpfull observation for you if you would like to go pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is now solved!
For future readers, I have taken [Paweł Łęgowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2841501/pawe%C5%82-%C5%81%C4%99gowski)'s advice and checked up on the scripts attached to the prefabs, they are trying to access their `_GCC` component on their `Awake()` when it only gains any value after they are instantiated. I have split up the function so that an external public function now deals with the `_GCC` and is called after I input a value to the empty pointer.